# Plotting in a nested function on matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide

I am struggling to use axes on my GUI because it says it is not defined. Here is the summary of the code :

```
function bitirme_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
axes(handles.axes1)
imshow('photo1.jpg');
...

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
theta=inverseKinematic(...)
...

function [Theta1,Theta2]=inverseKinematic(angle1,angle2,angle3,desCorX,desCorY)
axes(handles.axes1);
....
plot(a,b);
....
```

Until the function inverseKinematic is called,everything works fine. However when it is called, the image doesn't turn to be a graphic and I see the error " Undefined variable "handles" or class "handles.axes3" " on matlab command window. Why can I not call axes(handles.axes1) in a nested function? What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each function has its own workspace, and callbacks generated by GUIDE share data associated with what is called the `handles structure`. Every components of the GUI (axes, pushbuttons, etc.) are associated with the figure in which they are located. Hence GUIDE already provides the callback functions with everything stored in the handles structure.

However, nested functions do not have implicit access to the data stored in the handles structure. You need to specifically provide those data to the functions. There are a couple options available, for example:

1) Provide the handles structure as an input argument to the function.

2) Use `getappdata` and `setappdata` functions to associate data with a figure or MATLAB's root

3) Retrieve the handles structure "by hand" at the very beginning of the nested functions like so for example:

```
function [Theta1,Theta2]=inverseKinematic(angle1,angle2,angle3,desCorX,desCorY)

handles = guidata(gcf)
axes(handles.axes1);
....
plot(a,b);
....

 %// Save the changes made to the handles structure.
guidata(handles to the figure,handles);
```

where `gcf` refers to the current figure. You can actually use the name of the figure or `hObject`.

Note that when using the command `plot`, you don't need to set the current axes before each call. You can use the `Parent` property inside the call to plot to select where to plot the data.

Example:

```
plot(a,b,'Parent',handles.axes1)
```

I hope that was clear enough!